compare string with size 3 characters
I am trying to verify if a string (string_view) is one of the "allowed" combinations.
String is always 3 ASCII characters - upper and lowercase - A, B, C. These are permutations of 3 elements.
There is same function for 2 elements and can be version with 4 elements later.
Input string for validate is user specified. It can be anything.
Currently thinking about something like this:
    constexpr uint32_t s2u(std::string_view s){
        using T = uint32_t;

        return
            (T(s[0]) << 8 * 0) |
            (T(s[1]) << 8 * 1) |
            (T(s[2]) << 8 * 2) ;
    }

    bool validate(std::string_view s){
        if (s.size() != 3)
            return false;

        switch( s2u(s) ){
        case s2u("abc") : case s2u("ABC") :
        case s2u("acb") : case s2u("ACB") :
        case s2u("bac") : case s2u("BAC") :
        case s2u("bca") : case s2u("BCA") :
        case s2u("cab") : case s2u("CAB") :
        case s2u("cba") : case s2u("CBA") : return true;
        default:
            return false;
        }
    }

Is there faster way to do it?
C solutions are welcome too.

update
Here is my updated code. I also decided to change the return type to string_view in order to always get uppercase.
This also seems to be much faster in quick c++ benchmark.
I do not care about endian-nes, since I do not need big and little endian functions to produce same code. I care only about return to be correct.
    constexpr static auto s2u(std::string_view s){
        using T = uint32_t;

        auto _ = [s](uint8_t i){
            char const up = 0x20;

            return T(s[i] | up) << 8 * i;
        };

        return _(0) | _(1) | _(2);
    }

    std::string_view validateIndex(std::string_view s){
        if (s.size() != 3)
            return "";

        switch( s2u(s) ){
        case s2u("ABC") : return "ABC";
        case s2u("ACB") : return "ACB";
        case s2u("BAC") : return "BAC";
        case s2u("BCA") : return "BCA";
        case s2u("CAB") : return "CAB";
        case s2u("CBA") : return "CBA";
        default:
            return "";
        }
    }


I’m voting to close this question because this belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

It doesn't. I don't want my code reviewed, I want to find fast solution to a problem.

You could force all characters to upper or lower case by | 0x202020 or & 0x1f1f1f (assuming ASCII encoding). That halves the size of the case table.

My gut tells compiler will have an easier job optimising return s == "abc" || s == "ABC" || ...;  than this thing. The only way to know for sure is to either look at generated assembly or profile both versions.

Basically you have written some hash function. To optimize this I would try to invent a hash function which gives same value for all permutations. Also when you do micro-optimization like this write performance test first!

@MartinBrown can you show me an example, and yes, all allowed letters are ABC and  E in 4 character version.

Is the s2u computation really necessary ? I mean wouldn't it be the same results if you work directly on the std:string_view values and do your comparisons based on it ? It would save all those s2u computations (maybe they can be resolved at compile time but still)

@Fareanor - with this algorithm, yes, because it is used for labels of the switch.

@Yksisarvinen My instinct is that the compiler will make a decent fist of this admittedly ugly code. The only question is whether there is a faster safe way to interpret the first 4 bytes of a string as a unique integer - if speed is absolutely of the essence. It depends critically on unstated things like what challenges with weird combos of characters input the code may be subject to. Or if all permutations are allowed to sort the hash so that all perms of string "ABC" map to "ABC" encoding.

I did some perf test and for gcc gains do not look great: https://quick-bench.com/q/CE9Q7hutUv0KMI7j98Lwshs2Ct8 (only 10% better then simple brutal force). But when clang was used difference is huge: https://quick-bench.com/q/Ubb3COqATVGsnGE24rsAjkBoUaA x13

You might want to write s2u() in two versions, to enable big- and little-endian CPUs to treat it as a word load and mask where possible (if alignment and overrun concerns actually permit).

This looks like all permutations of ABC. So just check that all the characters are different and don't contain anything other than A, B, or C.

Are there constraints about letters which are neither abcABC? as with "good" constraint s[0]*s[1]*s[2] == 'a' * 'b' * 'c' || s[0]*s[1]*s[2] == 'A' * 'B' * 'C'  (in fact any hash which is invariant to the permutation)

I'll edit the question.

@Jarod I had same idea, but your proposal, have collisions which have to be verified. It would work if a b and c are represented by prime numbers.

@MarekR: As I said, it depends of other letter ranges, no needs of strictly prime (there are not), "just" all co-primes (ASCII range 'A'-'Z' is)

Here is alternative solution with lookup table and permutation resistant hash function:
constexpr auto makeLookUpTable()
{
    std::array<unsigned char, 256> lookUp{};
    lookUp['a'] = 1;
    lookUp['b'] = 2;
    lookUp['c'] = 3;
    lookUp['A'] = 5;
    lookUp['B'] = 7;
    lookUp['C'] = 11;
    return lookUp;
}

constexpr auto lookUpTable = makeLookUpTable();
constexpr uint32_t compose_chars_2(unsigned char a, unsigned char b, unsigned char c) noexcept
{
    return lookUpTable[a] * lookUpTable[b] * lookUpTable[c];
}

bool validate_lookup(std::string_view s)
{
    static constexpr auto lowerHash = compose_chars_2('a', 'b', 'c');
    static constexpr auto upperHash = compose_chars_2('A', 'B', 'C');
    if (s.size() != 3)
        return false;
        
    auto hash = compose_chars_2(s[0], s[1], s[2]);
    return (hash == lowerHash) || (hash == upperHash);
}

OR here is 2D look up table solution (assuming there is no 0 in use):
constexpr auto make2dLookUpTable()
{
    std::array<std::array<char, 256>, 256> t{};
    t['a']['b'] = 'c';
    t['b']['a'] = 'c';
    t['b']['c'] = 'a';
    t['c']['b'] = 'a';
    t['c']['a'] = 'b';
    t['a']['c'] = 'b';

    t['A']['B'] = 'C';
    t['B']['A'] = 'C';
    t['B']['C'] = 'A';
    t['C']['B'] = 'A';
    t['C']['A'] = 'B';
    t['A']['C'] = 'B';
    return t;
}

bool validate_lookup_2d(std::string_view s) noexcept
{   
    static constexpr auto lookUp = make2dLookUpTable();
    if (s.size() != 3)
        return false;
    return lookUp[static_cast<unsigned char>(s[0])][static_cast<unsigned char>(s[1])] == s[2];
}

Comparing to your solution, both solutions are faster on gcc:

Only 2D look up table is faster on clang:

The biggest advantage of this solution is, that when you decide to cover permutation with mixed case of letters, it will be easy to do and most probably will be fastest solution on all compilers (Didn't test this since cooperation require update of other solutions too).

Wonder if or is not faster than * (so instead of prime, take power of 2)

wow, another crazy idea - make a table with zeroes, put distinct bits for a,b,c, then do "or", then compare with combined value. Definitely will check this just for the sport!

Little faster with gcc Demo

Just realized, 2D solution take 64 KB - same as Apple ][
